# downloading file from server to local machine using javascript and java

Tags: java, javascript, html

Whenever I click on one button it has to get one directory from other server and has to download onto the local machine. How can I do that using java and javascript.?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I'm using linux Os.
Whenever I click on Download button from local machine(IP address:10.180.66.33), it has to connect to server(IP address:10.180.14.2) with username,passwd and it has to download one directory /home/alvin/project1/ to local machine(10.180.66.33). How can I do this?

Comment: Erm, simply change the URL to point to the file you need. Done, now the browser will handle it - it will pop up with "Do you want to save this file". You CANNOT force a download. Or rather, you might be able to, but you shouldn't.

Comment: It works only for the files which are present on same machine, but my question is to download files which are present on other machine

Answer (score 2):

Please go through [Download file in Servlet](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-downloading-file-from-the-server-in-servlet)